# operator norm and spectral radius

Tags: matrices, normed-spaces, spectral-theory

is it true that the operator norm of a matrix $A$ is smaller than 1 if its spectral radius $\rho(A)$ is smaller than 1?

many thanks for any help, it is much appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

No. Consider for example
$$
\begin{bmatrix}0&2\\0&0\end{bmatrix}.
$$
Its spectral radius is $0$, and its operator norm is $2$.

Now, for **normal** operators, the operator norm and the spectral radius agree.

Comment: You are welcome :)